# Notify after 24 hours, after insert a row in db

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, push-notification, notifications

Working on complain management system, If new complain register and it is not closed after 24 hours it should be notify or escalated to the concern users.
I am not sure what should i do for it.
Application in Asp.net(MVC4) and using sql.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Try adding a timestamp if you don't have one already for the complains table, and use a cronjob to periodically scan for complains older than 24 hours. You could lunch an event in your app and do whatever you wish in a listener.

Comment: Using sql server ms.

Comment: Dear @Dan, what should be the cronjob timing?

Comment: It depends on your business requirements, it might be every hour or every minute, or it could use a while true loop inside to scan continuously for complains that are expired. And you could use linux [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) in case it fails